# Communicating through Power Line Communication using STM32 and QCA7000

Tags: stm32, communication, spi, qualcomm, powerline

I am currently using the QCA7000 for Power Line Communication (PLC) by utilizing the STM32 as a master in the SPI protocol, with the QCA7000 acting as a slave. I have consulted the document at **https://chargebyte.com/assets/Downloads/an4_rev5.pdf**, but I couldn't find any information about Power Line Communication using the QCA7000. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: First step would be to see if you can read the `SPI REG SIGNATURE` register. Apparently it should have the value `0xAA55`.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I have read and recorded some registers, and I have confirmed the answer to be 0xAA55. However, I would like to discuss the issue of Powerline Communication. Specifically, I want to transmit information through the power lines rather than just reading and writing on a single QCA7000 device. I want two QCA7000 devices to communicate with each other through the power lines

Comment: From what I can tell the device basically functions like an Ethernet adapter. But we have no idea how you've got all this wired up. From a software point of view, I guess the next step would be to send a single packet from one device and receive it on the other.